# getResources Modx return null?

Tags: modx, getresource

I am trying to access some TV from another resource using getResources, but nothing is returned.

Here is my code sample

```
 [[getResources? 
      &resources=`13` 
      &tvPrefix=`tv.` 
      &tpl=`@CODE:[[+tv.DefaultEmail]]` 
      &showHidden=`1` 
      &includeContent=`1` 
      &includeTVs=`1` 
      &processTVs=`1` 
 ]]
```

Comment: turn on debuggong, grab the SQL from the log, run it and see if anything is actually being returned.  the problem looks like it's with your &tpl attribute. and take a peek here: http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=42475&page=1

Comment: Looks like that's the MIGX format for the inline template code which uses `@CODE:` instead of `@INLINE`. It should be `@INLINE [[+tv.DefaultEmail]]` - see the examples in this section - https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources#getResources-Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use @INLINE for the template parameter (see @FILE and @INLINE tpls in https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources#getResources-TemplatingProperties)

```
&tpl=`@INLINE [[+tv.DefaultEmail]]`
```

But I would better install [FastField](http://modx.com/extras/package/fastfield) to use the following tag syntax [[#13.DefaultEmail]].